# Undefined function in object literal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-literal

Hi Im trying to make an image gallery similar to instagram that loads images on scroll. Im trying it as an object literal variable but am getting an undefined method for this.showPics...  getMore is called from an ajax success method. Is this a scope issue because of the scroller being called in the .scroll? How should I do this? BTW showPics is defined I just didnt paste it in.. Thanks

```
var Pics{
    showPics: function() {
        //loop thru images
    }
    scroller: function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            this.showPics();
        }
    }
    getMore: function(){
        $(window).scroll(this.scroller);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `showPics()` defined? Also you are missing a comma after the `scroller:` function

Comment: sorry i just updated it

Comment: Added syntax correction - you were missing assignment after Pics, and commas after each member function definition

Comment: @ZlatinZlatev : How do you know he has put the commas? It could be that "THAT" is the thing which was missing?

Comment: @ZlatinZlatev - your edit (reverted, it seems) should be an answer, because it looks like it fixes the OP's problem.

Comment: @ZlatinZlatev please don't "fix" code in the question, when doing so might render the question meaningless. Your edits definitely make sense as an answer; as an edit, the original code and your explanation will be invisible to almost everyone.

Comment: OK, added syntax correction as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function, `this` doesnt refer to the object anymore, but to the window. Try using `bind` like that :

```
$(window).scroll(this.scroller.bind(this));
```

It will change the reference of `this` inside the `scroller` function to the current object.

Also, you have syntax errors in your object, but I assume that you just made a pseudo code for the question, right?

Comment: yeah this worked..I thought it had something to do with that. thanks! yeah I just pasted in pseudo code...

Answer (score 2):

Correcting syntax produces:

```
var Pics = {
    showPics: function() {
        //loop thru images
    },
    scroller: function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            this.showPics();
        }
    },
    getMore: function(){
        $(window).scroll(this.scroller);
    }
};
```

You were missing assignment after Pics and commas between member functions.

EDIT: Combined with https://stackoverflow.com/a/25184634/481422 answer from @Karl-André Gagnon it produces something alike http://jsfiddle.net/zlatin_zlatev/bue3ytek/

If this is alike what you need, please accept Karl-André Gagnon's comment as an answer.

Comment: If he get the error `undefined method for this.showPics`, it probably mean that his code is fine, else it would be `Unexpected token {`. He just didn't paste it well in the question. Even with your good fix, he'll still get the undefined error. Anyway, that's just my 2 cents!

Comment: I do agree, however when I posted this as an edit to the question, I was advised to put it as an answer.

Comment: Yes, I did followed that conversation. To be honest with you, I wouldn't know what to do. On one hand, my reasoning is *probably* right following the the error message. On the other hand, it is true that it drastically change the code in the question which **could have been** the problem. So hmm.. Yeah, i'd probably keep that answer until the OP said that it is pseudo code... I guess. It is as you feel.

Comment: Combining your answer with syntax correction (and minor tweaks to negate a logic check) produces http://jsfiddle.net/zlatin_zlatev/bue3ytek/1/

Comment: did that (was using anonymous jsfiddle and missed adding jquery reference when I transferred it to a registered user one)